# How to configure location of preferences

Tags: arduino-ide, raspberrypi

I had been using Arduino 1.0.5 on my Pi, and in September last year downloaded `arduino-1.8.4-linux32.tar.xz` (which I have since updated).

I have been successfully using 1.8.5, but just noticed it seems to have been `/home/pi/.arduino15` for preferences and packages.

I probably did this inadvertently when I was briefly running both 1.8.4 and 1.0.5 (which is long gone). I have `/home/pi/.arduino` but this only contains `preferences.txt` and has not been used since September.

There seems to be no  way of changing this to the normal directory; where is this configured?

Comment: That is the normal directory.

Comment: they can be in a couple places, grep is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the introduction of many enhancements in the IDE, such as the Boards Manager, and the Arduino Builder system, it was decided that this would break backwards compatibility with older versions of the IDE.  In version 1.5.0 of the IDE it was therefore decided that the location of all the Arduino data files (of which there are now many, not just a `preferences.txt` file) should be moved to a new location, and `.arduino15` was chosen to reflect the current version.

Since then a *version number war* broke out between the two Arduino factions, which was then subsequently resolved, and we ended up with the 1.8.x group of versions. These, since they haven't introduced anything drastic to the underlying system since 1.5.x, haven't needed to change the location of the data files (indeed, to do so would be undesirable), so it has remained as `.arduino15`.

I don't believe it's possible to change the preferences location, since the only place would be in preferences, and it would need to load the preferences to know where to load the preferences from.

If you *really* need to access the `preferences.txt` file yourself as `~/.arduino/preferences.txt` (why would you?) then you can just delete the old `.arduino` directory and create a link to the new one:

```
$ rm -rf .arduino
$ ln -s /home/pi/.arduino15 .arduino
```

---

Update:

There is a command-line argument to the Arduino IDE that lets you set the location of the preferences.txt file (detailed [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc)):

```
$ arduino --preferences-file /home/pi/.arduino/preferences.txt
```

However what that will do with an old preferences.txt file is anyone's guess.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I probably jumped to the conclusion that this was related to the older 1.0.5. The question now becomes do I need `.arduino` and where did it come from? It seems to date from the installation of 1.8.4

Comment: `.arduino` was created by 1.0.5.